Adverb modifying two other adverbs
In the phrase "can express herself very fluently and precisely," does "very" modify both "fluently" AND "precisely"? Or just "fluently"? Or is it ambiguous?
Additionally, do you consider precisely an absolute adverb? I do, so "very" should not be used to modify an absolute adverb like "precisely".

Precise isn't absolute. 10.123 is more precise than 10. See also.

This Q is about adjectives but the same principle applies

I
There is an ambiguity, but in those cases where people do use this form instead of the form with the more careful order there is a preference for a reading in which the premodifier applies to both adjectives. This is explained in A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language 5Quirk et al., 1985).

(CoGEL § 13.79) Coordination of adjectives and adjective phrases
Adjective phrases are coordinated in:

The journey was long and extremely arduous.
Our team is very fit, very keen, and ready to face the strongest competition in the world.

In the following, there is a coordination of adjective heads:

I'm feeling younger and healthier than I have felt for years.

But in the following, there is an ambiguity, according to whether the
premodifier belongs to the first conjoin or to both conjoins:

The souvenirs they bought were very cheap and gaudy.

It is unclear whether the analysis should be:
           [very cheap] and [gaudy] OR very [cheap] and [gaudy]
But the second reading, in which the premodifier applies to the whole
sequence, is preferred. A change in the order of the words will eliminate the
ambiguity:

The souvenirs they bought were [gaudy] and [very cheap].


II
"Precise" has to be gradable; here is an example of gradable use in the text of teachers expalining absolute adjectives.

"Using absolute adjectives correctly can elevate your writing and make your sentences more precise. Here’s a step-by-step guide:" (Ex.Examples.com)

The 2-grams below show that "precise" is being used with the usual terms compatible with gradable adjectives.


In normative grammar, modifiers of sets affect all objects in sets: A(B+C) = AB+AC.
Fluency is the ability to comprehend and communicate with ease and precision. Generally, someone is considered to be not fluent, nearly fluent, or fluent. Unless specified otherwise, proficiency in speech, reading, and writing are assumed.
"Can express herself very fluently and precisely" is struggling to say "is fluent in" or "communicates fluently."
If this is your writing, mind that "very" rarely make words work harder. It usually indicates that stronger words are needed.

This is from the Council of Europe's CERF levels explaining who they consider to be at a C2 level! https://www.coe.int/en/web/common-european-framework-reference-languages/level-descriptions  I could see that they struggled to find a word for very fluent... maybe mastery?

Quirk et al (above) say that there does exist an ambiguity:   very cheap and gaudy = gaudy and very cheap OR [very cheap] and [very gaudy] ... but that the default reading is the latter (mathematical distribution, as you indicate). In speech, cadence can indicate either reading (eg "The souvenirs they bought were very cheap ... and gaudy."
